# Getting only the first object from an array returned from async operation

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql

I'm working on the backend for my application. I connect and query my mongoDB database/collection with mongoose and GraphQL. Currently, I am trying to create an async function that gets a user's most recent workout from their log (if there is one) for my GraphQL resolvers. I have come up with this:

```
async getMostRecentWorkout(_, __, context) {
    const user = checkAuth(context); // checks for and get's authenticated user details

    try {
        const workouts = await Workout.find({ username: user.username }).sort({ createdAt: -1 }); 
        return workouts;
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run this on the GraphQL playground, it gets all of the authenticated user's workouts. For this query, I only want to get the first object that is the array that is returned (first object should always be most recent workout as it is sorted). I have tried using `return workouts[0]` but it returns an error with this message `"Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field \"Query.getMostRecentWorkout\"."`

Comment: use findOne, and return if not null [workout]

Comment: `workouts[0]` not `workout[0]`? But like @Nonik wrote, you shouldn't load the whole list of workouts from the database in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Nonik, this worked. Do you mind explaining why it needs to be put in square brackets though?

Comment: @JLI_98 was under impression error you were getting is from GraphQL, that it expects array, if not, just return your object, just remember to handle null, as findOne will return null if not found

Comment: @Bergi, that was just a typo in the question. However, thank you for letting me know about loading from the database.

Answer (score 0):

So to get recent You've to sort reversed by `createdAt` that You already did and get 1 item from big result using `limit(1)`:

So Your code simply:

```
async getMostRecentWorkout(_, __, context) {
    const user = checkAuth(context); // checks for and get's authenticated user details
    const query = { username: user.username };
    return (
      await Workout.find(query)
                   .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
                   .limit(1).lean()
    )[0];
}
```

btw, no need for try catch if You're throwing it again from inside catch.